# Appending values to dictionary/list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a `mylist = [[a,b,c,d],...[]]` with 650 lists inside. I am trying to insert this into a relational database with dictionaries. I have the following code:

```
for i in mylist:
    if len(i) == 4: 
       cve_ent = {'state':[], 'muni':[], 'area':[]}
       cve_ent['state'].append(i[1])
       cve_ent['muni'].append(i[2])
       cve_ent['area'].append(i[3])
```

However this code just yields the last list in `mylist` in the dictionary. I have tried also with a counter and a `while loop` but I cannot make it run.

I do not know if this is the fastest way to store the data, what I will do is compare the `values` of the first and second `keys` with other tables to multiply the `values` of the third `key`.

Comment: Are you doing something with `cve_ent`? If not, of course it is just the last one, because you overwrite it each time

Comment: Your append statement has 'list_[1]' etc., in it, should it be 'i[1]' or was that just a typo in the problem statement?

Comment: A few things
(1) Are you positive all of your lists are length 4?
(2) What is list_ ?

Comment: It was a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: All lists are lenght 4. @tehhowch what do you mean exactly? What I am trying to do is that each different "state" is saved to the list in the order it appers in the original file, so I can order also the "muni" and the "area". In the end the purpose is to have four dictionaries (from four files), each with information that can relate to the other. Is this more clear?

Comment: @Daniel every time `myList` has a list with length 4, you wipe `cve_ent` back to the empty slate. If you intend it aggregate values, you need to initialize it outside of your loop, as @JMB's answer indicates

Comment: Yeap, this solved the problem (very stupid from my part btw). The question then is do you reckon this could be "the best way to link" the files? Each file contains the same 'variables' such as **state** and **muni** but differ in the 'area/size/etc'.

Comment: @Daniel questions on design and efficiency seem more related to code review, rather than SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, pull

```
cve_ent = {'state':[], 'muni':[], 'area':[]}
```

out of your for loop. That will solve issues with re-writing things.